# Prove that the sequence $\left\{\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right\}_1^\infty$ converges to 0.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Prove that the sequence $\left\{\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right\}_1^\infty$ converges to 0.

I'm missing something. I doubt that I'm really doing anything from " $\frac{1}{n+1}$ " on. I set it $< \epsilon$ and then define my lowest n value, $n_0$, by manipulating that inequality. Is that right? If this is the right approach, why? Defining  $\epsilon$ and $n_0$ in terms of each other makes me think I can always make the inequality I make at the end concluding my proof.

Thank you for your help in explaining this!!

$\left|\frac{n}{n^2+1}-0\right| = \frac{n}{n^2+1} \leq \frac{n}{n^2+n} = \frac{1}{n+1}$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Let $n_0$ be the smallest integer such that $n \geq n_0>\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$. Equivalently, $\epsilon>\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Thus $\left|\frac{n}{n^2+1}-0\right|<\frac{1}{n+1} < \epsilon$,$\forall n_0 \geq n$, so $\frac{n}{n^2+1}_1^\infty \rightarrow 0.$

Comment: Is $\frac{n}{n^2+1}_{1}^{\infty} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+1}$?

Comment: It's false that
$$\frac{n}{n^2+1} \leq \frac{n}{n^2+n}$$

$$\frac{2}{5}=\frac{2}{2^2+1} \geq \frac{2}{2^2+2}=\frac{2}{6}$$

Comment: Apparently isn't a [convergent sum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+n%2F%28n%5E2%2B1%29%2C+n%3D1+to+n%3Dinfinity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\underline{\textbf{Proof}}$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.

We need to show $\exists \ N_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|\frac{n}{n^2+1}-0|< \epsilon \implies |\frac{n}{n^2 +1}|<\epsilon$.

We know that $|\frac{n}{n^2 +1}| = \frac{n}{n^2 +1} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Note also that $\frac{n}{n^2+1}\leq\frac{n}{n^2 +n} = \frac{1}{n+1} \forall n\in\mathbb{N} \ \ \ $. (*)

---

$\underline{\textbf{Rough Work:}}$

We now have that $\frac{1}{n+1} < \epsilon \implies n+1> \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, since all values are positive.

$\implies n> \frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$

---

Now, for the given $\epsilon > 0$, using the Archimedean Property, choose $N_\epsilon > \frac{1}{\epsilon} -1$.

Thus, for $\forall n \geq N_\epsilon$, we have:

$n\geq N_\epsilon > \frac{1}{\epsilon} -1 $

$\implies n+1 \geq N_\epsilon +1 > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$

$\implies \frac{1}{n+1}\leq\frac{1}{N_\epsilon+1} < \epsilon$.

Now, from (*), we have

$\frac{n}{n^2 +1}\leq\frac{1}{N_\epsilon+1}<\epsilon$

$\implies \frac{n}{n^2 +1} < \epsilon$

Thus proving that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{n}{n^2 +1})=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$0\leq \frac{n}{n^2+1}\leq \frac{n}{n^2}$$

Comment: Oops. Is it right if I make this change --- $\left|\frac{n}{n^2+1}-0\right| = \frac{n}{n^2+1} \leq \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}$ ---- and then say $n\geq n_0>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ , $\frac{n}{n^2+1} \leq \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$, $ \forall n\geq n_0$ ?

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Comment: What do you mean take n big enough? What would need to be included in my write up to say that?

Comment: Nothing, it's good! You already said in $n\geq n_0 \geq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$

Comment: Ok awesome. So now I'm confused about why. It seems a little bit like magic that I get to a point and say this is $<\epsilon$ and then from that get an n and then I'm done. I don't understand the meaning behind the $n, n_0, \epsilon$ string of inequalities.

Comment: ok, it's like a game, someone give ANY $\epsilon>0$ and you have to show a $n_0$ that if, $n>n_0,\ |\frac{n}{n^2+1}-0|<\epsilon$.

As $0<\epsilon$, using the Archimedean property of real numbers, you can take $n_0$ big enough to $0<1/n_0<\epsilon$.
But so, you found the $n_0$ 
(Sorry my english)

Comment: Did you agree whith me that it's possible take $n$ big enough to $1/n<0,00001$ for example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17478/discussion-between-bamboozled-and-aldo).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: $\frac{n}{n^2+1} = \frac{n+i-i}{(n+i)(n-i)} = \frac{i}{n+i} = \frac{-i}{n-i} \xrightarrow{x \to \infty} 0 $